# WebService restfull into my spring mvc portlet?

Tags: rest, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc

I'm new in liferay. I'm working at a project that is divided on two parts(data project and business project)..the data project contains all my entities and services and the interaction with database. the second is a portlet project..I have to consume restfull web services in my portlet without using a service builder.. any ideas??

Comment: Do you intend that your portlet (business part) need to expose REST webservices that need to be consumed by someone else, and you haven't idea on how to expose them?

Comment: thanks for your reply..yes my portlet is on the business part... i will expose REst webservices from the data part to be consumed on my portlet.. i haven't idea about consuming them in my portlet..

Answer (score 0):

If your data part need to expose WS to your business part... then I don't understand why using LR.

In my opinion the best is to use ServiceBuilder to expose data locally (in the same JVM) or remotely (by SOAP/REST). So you can access them by the same portlet business logic, or by external code by WS.
Creating a MVN LR portlet it will create two modules (one for data and one for logic) and you can separate the logic parts.

By the way... following your requirements... your data part need for a business logic (your or by a 3rd part library) to expose data by REST. First options I'm thinking are to:
1. provide a servlet mapping your request and exposing data
2. OR integrate a REST server engine to map your requests

Then your logic should contain a REST client to access your server.